# Symfony clone an entity from one entity manager to another with FosUser

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I want to copy data from one database to another. I get two Customers from two different entity managers (emLocal,emRemote).

The customer entity is in a oneToOne relationship with FosUser 
**The flush try to insert a blank user.** even if I try to detach concerned entities and set every relation to null.

I read from [github](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1294%22github%22) that FosUserBundle is not designed to works with two entity manager

```
        $remoteCustomer = $order->getCustomer();
        $onlineCustomer = $this->emLocal->getRepository("LilWorksStoreBundle:Customer")->findOneBy(array("remoteUser"=>$remoteCustomer->getUser()->getId()));
        if(!$onlineCustomer){
            $onlineCustomer = clone $remoteCustomer;

        }
        $this->emLocal->detach($onlineCustomer->getUser());
        $onlineCustomer->getUser()->setCustomer(null);
        $onlineCustomer->setUser(null);
        $this->emLocal->persist($onlineCustomer);
        $this->emLocal->flush();
```

How I can prevent this INSERT?

Comment: please cautious with cloning entities in Doctrine, especially when you want to reuse them within one request, standard `clone` usually creates no deep copy, some initializers might be not as expected etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use another `Entity Manager` to save `$onlineCustomer`.

```
$this->emOnline->persist($onlineCustomer);
$this->emOnline->flush();
```